# Sampling for multiple columns at once and return to aggregated dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3    Column 4
  Male        35        USA         DC
  Female      10        USA         NYC
```

I've agregated this dataframe to calculate the number of unique values in each column and the respective percentage of the total number of rows.

So my new dataframe looks like this:

I've got a data frame that looks like this (this is just examplary):

```
  Column Name   Nominal  Percent 
1 Col1             3      1.00
2 Col2          69333    99.51
3 Col3          65766    94.40
4 Col4          60727    87.16
```

What I want for the second dataframe is to create a third column - sample modality. The new column should be a sample of each column. Like this:

```
  Column Name   Nominal  Percent  Sample_1
1 Col1             3       1.00     Male
2 Col2           69333     99.51    25
```

I can't recall how to pull this off automatically for each column. I don't want to manually type each column-name. Any hints?

Comment: `newdat$Sample_1 <- sapply(origdat, sample, size=1)`? Note that they will likely be upconverted to `character` (since at least one of your columns is `character`, none of them will retain their `numeric` or `integer` class.

Comment: @r2evans it took me a while to realize that I've arranged the aggregated dataframe. But it works perfectly :) Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, yes of course, the ordering is relevant. If that's an issue, then you can generate a temporary `data.frame(ColumnName=names(origdat), Sample_1=sapply(origdat, sample, size=1), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, then use `merge` or any of the joins within `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness.

Data, slightly modified to make them consistent and R-friendly (no spaces):

```
origdat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
Column_1   Column_2   Column_3    Column_4
  Male        35        USA         DC
  Female      10        USA         NYC')

newdat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
  Column_Name   Nominal  Percent 
1 Column_1          3      1.00
2 Column_2       69333    99.51
3 Column_3       65766    94.40
4 Column_4       60727    87.16')
```

Verbose method, using a temporary `data.frame` to store the samplings:

```
set.seed(2)
tempdat <- data.frame(Column_Name = names(origdat),
                      Sample_1 = sapply(origdat, sample, size=1),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Merging it in with base R:

```
merge(newdat, tempdat, by="Column_Name", all=TRUE)
#   Column_Name Nominal Percent Sample_1
# 1    Column_1       3    1.00     Male
# 2    Column_2   69333   99.51       10
# 3    Column_3   65766   94.40      USA
# 4    Column_4   60727   87.16       DC
```

Merging with `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::left_join(newdat, tempdat, by="Column_Name")
#   Column_Name Nominal Percent Sample_1
# 1    Column_1       3    1.00     Male
# 2    Column_2   69333   99.51       10
# 3    Column_3   65766   94.40      USA
# 4    Column_4   60727   87.16       DC
```